# How to remove black space from png data pulled from selenium?

Tags: python, image, selenium, png, python-imaging-library

I have the following png binary data that I was able to pull from a page utilizing selenium with the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=39713077')
data = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
```

However, the image looks like the following and I'd like to remove the black space around it:
[image]

The image is located here: http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=39713077

Is there a way to remove the black space utilizing the binary data or get selenium to pull only the image and not the black background?

I've tried to utilize Pil, but I've only found ways to remove white space and not black space, plus it's difficult to turn it back to binary data, which I need.

I've also looked into the [PNG Module](https://pythonhosted.org/pypng/png.html), but I couldn't figure out how to turn it back to binary as well.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to directly get the screenshot of the image:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=39713077')
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img")
image = element.screenshot_as_png()
```

But unfortunately Firefox doesn't yet implement this feature.

Another way would be to crop the screenshot to the targeted element:

```
import StringIO
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=39713077')
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img")
rect = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect();", element)
screenshot = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
img = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(screenshot))
img_cropped = image.crop((rect['x'], rect['y'], rect['width'], rect['height']))
img_cropped.save('screenshot.png')
```

Comment: Thanks! I think you meant img.crop instead of image.crop by the way. Also, img_cropped.save('screenshot.png') is returning a 'TypeError: integer argument expected, got float.'  The last piece is getting this in binary data format.